# playground does not track the uiimage

Tags: ios, xcode6, swift-playground

I am working with xcode 6, and I am recreating the image code that was demoed during session 401 "what is new in xcode 6). I put an image in my Bundle resource directory, and created a playground file. Playground does not execute the command var sample = UIImage(named: "img") or any command after. Any Idea?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup the resource path from utilities?

View > Utilities > Show Utilities

When the right pane opens
Change Resource Path (Not Location) to Absolute Path
Click the little folder icon under Resource Path and then select the folder where you image is..

Then run your code above..

if you already did that part, what does the console output say?

Comment: yes I did this, but as soon as start typing a new line I get an alert window with the follow: Playground execution terminated because the playground process exited unexpectedly. ????   the resource path after I change it to absolute and select the path is: /Users/ehassan/Desktop